# HowTo parse this (see description) text file in Pharo Smalltalk

Tags: parsing, text, csv, smalltalk, pharo

I want to parse a textfile in Pharo Smalltalk, that has the structure outlined below into a Smalltalk object called TestResults, that has instance variables for all the data elements:

```
Properties:

Name: Value
Name: Value
...

Settings:

Category
    SubCategory
        Name=Value
    SubCategory
        Name=Value
        Name=Value
...

Column1 Column2 Column3 ...
Value Value Value...
...
```

I thought about using [NeoCSV](https://github.com/svenvc/docs/blob/master/neo/neo-csv-paper.md) for the tab-separated-value part at the end of the file, but i do not know how to parse the beginning of the file and how to combine this (if this approach is possible) with NeoCSV.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I advise you to have a look at PetitParser. See http://pharobooks.gforge.inria.fr/PharoByExampleTwo-Eng/latest/PetitParser.pdf and http://www.themoosebook.org/book/internals/petit-parser. Don't hesitate to create more questions on stackoverflow about this if you need help writing your parser.

Comment: Thank you, it worked extremely well and elegant! I also recommend anyone who wants to learn about PetitParser to watch these two videos by Tudor Girba: (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vgiJG3Vd6KU) and (http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEJqhWq4l1I). They really helped me to understand what it is all about and get a feeling for it.